# Excel VBA Help for Membership Fee Calculator

Tags: excel, vba

My course project is required to prepare the following program.
This is a Membership fee calculation program for a Sport club. Charges change as follows. This should make without any Date,Year or Month functions.

2014 - 01
to
2014 - 02 ---> $100  (2014 is Year 01 is Month)

2014 - 03 
to
2018 - 02 --->$120

2018 - 03 
to
2019--------> -$150

https://i.stack.imgur.com/secY3.jpg

I could make a variable (x1) for calculate months of any year range for above program.

```
X1 = (((Val(C.Value) - 1) - Val(A.Value)) * 12) + (12 - Val(B.Value) + Val(D.Value) + 1)
```

Calculation starts from year 2014. If start from 2014-01 or 2014-02 that should be display in A1. If end Year is greater than 2014 ,A1 value should display 200 and 
Rest of other value should display in B1 like as below picture.
(meaning , When end year value(C) is > 2014 , calculations 
stop and Display that value in A1 and Other calculation go forward and that rest should be display in B1)
https://i.stack.imgur.com/6gKQO.jpg

**Issue:** I can't stop B1 values if C value > 2018 and D value > 02

**Question:** How can I modify this program in Excel VBA being correct till 2018-02, but resulting in a wrong answer after 2018-03 and 2019.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

A1.Value = 0
B1.Value = 0
D1.Value = 0

X1 = (((Val(C.Value) - 1) - Val(A.Value)) * 12) + (12 - Val(B.Value) + Val(D.Value) + 1)
X2 = (((Val(C.Value) - 1) - Val(A.Value)) * 12) + (10 - Val(B.Value) + Val(D.Value) + 1)
X3 = (((Val(C.Value) - 1) - Val(A.Value)) * 12) + (11 - Val(B.Value) + Val(D.Value))
X4 = (((Val(C.Value) - 1) - Val(A.Value)) * 12) + (12 - Val(B.Value) + Val(D.Value) + 1) - Val(D.Value) + 2
X11 = (((Val(C.Value) - 1) - Val(A.Value)) * 12) + (12 - Val(B.Value) + Val(D.Value) + 1) - Val(D.Value) + 1
X5 = (((Val(C.Value) - 1) - Val(A.Value)) * 12) + 12
X6 = (((Val(C.Value) - 1) - Val(A.Value)) * 12) + 11
X7 = (((Val(C.Value) - 1) - Val(A.Value)) * 12) + (12 - Val(B.Value) + Val(D.Value)) - Val(D.Value) + 1
X8 = (((Val(C.Value) - 1) - Val(A.Value)) * 12) + (12 - Val(B.Value) + Val(D.Value)) - Val(D.Value) + 2
X9 = (((Val(C.Value) - 1) - Val(A.Value)) * 12) + (12 - Val(B.Value) + Val(D.Value) + 1) - Val(D.Value) + 1
X10 = (((Val(C.Value) - 1) - Val(A.Value)) * 12) + (12 - Val(B.Value) + Val(D.Value) + 1) - Val(D.Value) + 2

Y1 = ((Val(A.Value)) * 0) + (Val(B.Value))

'2014 January and February ===========================================================

If Val(A.Value) = 2014 And Val(B.Value) = 1 And Val(C.Value) > 2014 And Val(D.Value) = 1 Then
    A1.Value = 2 * Y1 * 100
End If

If Val(A.Value) = 2014 And Val(B.Value) = 1 And Val(C.Value) = 2014 And Val(D.Value) = 1 Then
    A1.Value = Y1 * 100
End If

If Val(A.Value) = 2014 And Val(B.Value) = 1 And Val(C.Value) >= 2014 And Val(D.Value) >= 2 Then
    A1.Value = 2 * Y1 * 100
End If

If Val(A.Value) = 2014 And Val(B.Value) = 2 And Val(C.Value) >= 2014 And Val(D.Value) <= 12 Then
    A1.Value = Y1 / 2 * 100
End If

'===================================================================================================

'2014- March to 2018 - February

If Val(A.Value) = 2014 And Val(B.Value) = 1 And Val(C.Value) < 2018 And Val(D.Value) >= 1 Then
    B1.Value = (X2 * 120)
End If

If Val(A.Value) = 2014 And Val(B.Value) = 2 And Val(C.Value) < 2018 And Val(D.Value) >= 1 Then
    B1.Value = (X3 * 120)
End If

If Val(A.Value) = 2014 And Val(B.Value) >= 3 And Val(C.Value) < 2018 And Val(D.Value) >= 1 Then
    B1.Value = (X1 * 120)
End If

If Val(A.Value) > 2014 And Val(B.Value) >= 1 And Val(C.Value) < 2018 And Val(D.Value) >= 1 Then
    B1.Value = (X1 * 120)
End If

If Val(A.Value) > 2014 And Val(B.Value) >= 1 And Val(C.Value) >= 2018 And Val(D.Value) >= 2 Then
    B1.Value = (X4 * 120)
End If

If Val(A.Value) > 2014 And Val(B.Value) >= 1 And Val(C.Value) >= 2018 And Val(D.Value) = 1 Then
    B1.Value = (X11 * 120)
End If

If Val(A.Value) = 2014 And Val(B.Value) = 1 And Val(C.Value) = 2018 And Val(D.Value) = 1 Then
    B1.Value = (X2 * 120)
End If

If Val(A.Value) = 2014 And Val(B.Value) = 1 And Val(C.Value) = 2018 And Val(D.Value) = 2 Then
    B1.Value = (X3 * 120)
End If

If Val(A.Value) = 2014 And Val(B.Value) = 2 And Val(C.Value) = 2018 And Val(D.Value) = 1 Then
    B1.Value = (X6 * 120)
End If

If Val(A.Value) = 2014 And Val(B.Value) = 2 And Val(C.Value) = 2018 And Val(D.Value) = 2 Then
    B1.Value = (X5 * 120)
End If

If Val(A.Value) = 2014 And Val(B.Value) >= 3 And Val(C.Value) = 2018 And Val(D.Value) = 1 Then
    B1.Value = (X9 * 120)
End If

If Val(A.Value) = 2014 And Val(B.Value) >= 3 And Val(C.Value) = 2018 And Val(D.Value) >= 2 Then
    B1.Value = (X10 * 120)
End If

If Val(A.Value) = 2014 And Val(B.Value) = 1 And Val(C.Value) = 2018 And Val(D.Value) > 2 Then
    B1.Value = (X7 * 120)
End If

If Val(A.Value) = 2014 And Val(B.Value) = 2 And Val(C.Value) = 2018 And Val(D.Value) >= 3 Then
    B1.Value = (X8 * 120)
End If

'===================================================================================================
Me.Answer = (Me.A1 + 0) + (Me.B1 + 0) + (Me.D1 + 0)

End Sub
```

Comment: Can you use CDate ? And is any date after 2018 - 03  counted as 150?

Comment: You should also post the code you have written so far, so you help someone to help you.

Comment: ^^ I think they attempted that with their X1 line though could be clearer. "I could" is a little vague as to whether they implemented.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure whether CDate and IsDate are disallowed. I also assume any date >="2018-03-01" is $150 though you can alter that to a between. If those are acceptable assumptions. I've concatenated "-01" to align with your presentation but perhaps you can also just directly attach without that step.

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub test()
    Dim x As String, var As String
    var = "2014-01"
    var = var & "-01"
    If Not IsDate(CDate(var)) Then
        Debug.Print "please ensure valid input"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    Select Case True
    Case var >= CDate("2018-03" & "-01")
        x = "$150"
    Case var >= CDate("2014-03" & "-01")
        x = "$120"
    Case var >= CDate("2014-01" & "-01")
        x = "$100"
    Case Else
        x = "undefined"
    End Select
    Debug.Print x
End Sub
```